# EEPROM Data Address Width

Tags: memory, memory-address, eeprom

I am beginner to electronics and embeds and I am struggling with some probably basic notation in EEPROM.I am using AT25640(64k(8192 x 8)) EEPROM and have confusion with data address width.

Array Addresses are from 0000-1FFF that means it has 2 Byte address width. is this correct or am i missing something here?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc0675.pdf) of the EEPROM, it can store about 8192 bytes. This means if you are going to define an int array let's say:

```
int theInt[6];
```

and a char array:

```
char theChar[6]="Hello";
```

both will have different sizes of bytes which you can get from sizeof() function easily. First one being 24, second being 26 bytes depending upon the compiler if I am correct.